# MySQL - Out of Memory

Tags: mysql, out-of-memory

I'm not even close to a server expert - used XAMPP to install phpmyadmin/mysql and everything was running smoothly until a few weeks ago. Was able to put a bandaid on the issue when these errors started happening by doubling some of the memory parameters (buffer size etc) but now these issues are occurring again. There is nothing else running on this machine except MySQL, so not sure how how we are running out of memory. I'm willing to try anything - haven't found very clear instructions on how to use 'ulimit' - any suggestions from any experienced MySQL Server admins out there on what might be causing this issue, and what I can try to fix it?

```
2016-08-24 12:26:48 2456 [ERROR] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Out of memory (Needed 767416 bytes)
2016-08-24 12:26:48 2456 [ERROR] Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space
2016-08-24 12:26:48 2456 [ERROR] Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space
2016-08-24 13:41:33 6188 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-08-24 13:41:33 16d0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
```

Comment: Some suggestions here - including reducing buffer sizes rather than increasing. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/why-does-mysql-say-im-out-of-memory

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Will start trying them out!

Answer (score 1):

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

All my answers were there. Again - i'm no server Admin, but basically my settings were all wrong in my.ini file. My innodb_buffer_pool_size was way too low, and my key_buffer_size was much too high. I'm guessing that the original settings were enough to get us buy as we were building the databases, but as tables/views/threads increased, performance was impacted.